# Added ruby PATH to enviornment variables still `grunt sass` does not work

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

Okay first I did this.

```
>grunt sass
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

And I thought this makes sense I need to add path to ruby so I did. Then I checked version of ruby and it did return something

```
>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x64-mingw32]
```

this means I have ruby installed. Now grunt sass should work but it does not and I am getting same old message.
This one:

```
>grunt sass
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

## UPDATE

I get following when I run `grunt-sass-force`:

```
>grunt sass --force
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Used --force, continuing.
'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

Comment: What happens when you use ``--force``? Have you installed ``sass``?

Comment: @zhon 
you mean like this:
`grunt sass --force` ?

I get following when I do `grunt-sass-force`


>grunt sass --force
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Used --force, continuing.
'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.

Comment: Have you installed the ``sass`` gem?

Comment: @zhon Thanks for the help, I did not have `sass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to install `sass` with `gem install sass`. Without the gem, you can't work with sass in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

`Sass` was originally built using the [ruby programming language](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). Running Sass on a `node` build system (ie., `grunt`, `gulp`, `webpack`) requires running both `ruby` and `Sass` and a way to connect them (ie., `grunt-contrib-sass`, `gulp-sass`, `sass-loader`).

Ruby plugins are called `gems`, installing plugins is easy:

```
gem install sass
```

On the other hand, [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) is a `c` implementations of `Sass` that do not require `ruby`. After installing `libsass`, you will need a way to connect `libsass` to `node`. You can do this with [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

```
npm install node-sass
```

Finally, `LESS` is a competitor to `Sass` which runs on `node` and will not require `ruby` or `libsass`.